# how to include html inside of javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have javascript jquery that looks like this:

```
var userInput = prompt("Liquid Handler #:", "Liquid Handler #:");
$(this).next('a').text('Liquid Handler #:' + userInput);
```

i would like to know how i can include html into the text something like this:

```
var userInput = prompt("Liquid Handler #:", "Liquid Handler #:");
$(this).next('a').text('Liquid Handler #:' + '<b>' + userInput + </b>);
```

how do i inject html into the javascript?

Comment: did u try changing the `text()` to `html()` ?

Comment: Your `</b>` isn't wrapped in single quotes...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `.html` instead of `.text`.

```
$(this).next('a').html('Liquid Handler #:<b>' + userInput + '</b>');
```

Answer (score 3):

jQuery's [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method should help.

Answer (score 1):

You could change your `.text` to `.html` but bear in mind this is prone to problems in the long run seeing as you'll have to escape anything that goes through it. A better way might be to do something like this:

```
$(this).next('a').text('Liquid Handler #:').append($("<b>").text(userInput));
```